# Efficiently reading foxpro DBF with python

Tags: python, foxpro, dbf, visual-foxpro

I've tried two modules for reading dbf files that work fine (dbf and dbfpy), but I have to read through the databases record by record to find stuff.  This is really slow for large databases.  Is there any module that can handle querying the tables or use CDX indexes?

Comment: Depending on your platform, I guess you can try OS-level external interfaces like ODBC/JDBC.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe `dbfpy` supports index files, and I know `dbf` does not.

However, in `dbf` you can create a temporary index and then query that:

```
big_table = dbf.Table('/path/to/some/big_table')
def criteria(record):
    "index the table using these fields"
    return record.income, record.age
index = big_table.create_index(key=criteria)
```

`index` can now be itereated over, or searched to return all matching records:

```
for record in index.search(match=(50000, 30)):
    print record
```

A sample table:

```
table = dbf.Table('tempu', 'name C(25); age N(3,0); income N(7,0);')
table.open()
for name, age, income in (
        ('Daniel', 33, 55000),
        ('Mike', 59, 125000),
        ('Sally', 33, 77000),
        ('Cathy', 41, 50000),
        ('Bob', 19, 22000),
        ('Lisa', 19, 25000),
        ('Nancy', 27, 50000),
        ('Oscar', 41, 50000),
        ('Peter', 41, 62000),
        ('Tanya', 33, 125000),
        ):
    table.append((name, age, income))

index = table.create_index(lambda rec: (rec.age, rec.income))
```

There are also methods to search for the beginning and ending of ranges:

```
# all the incomes of those who are 33
for rec in index.search(match=(33,), partial=True):
    print repr(rec)
print
# all the incomes of those between the ages of 40 - 59, inclusive
start = index.index_search(match=(40, ), nearest=True)
end = index.index_search(match=(60, ), nearest=True)
for rec in index[start:end]:
    print repr(rec)
```

which prints:

```
Daniel                    33  55000
Sally                     33  77000
Tanya                     33 125000

Cathy                     41  50000
Oscar                     41  50000
Peter                     41  62000
Mike                      59 125000
```

Comment: This took about twice as long.  I'm guessing because it had to create the index and then loop through it.

Comment: @user3727436: Can you edit your answer and post the code you tried?  Creating the index does loop through the entire table once, but after that (with the proper idioms) lookup should be using a binary algorythm.